# Mysql left join with condition in right table

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while, hope anyone help me. I am having two table, the first table is

**Table Name : OnlineTest**

```
OnlineTestId     category    subcategory                                                                   
     1            English      Spelling                                                                    
     2            English      Grammar
     3            English      Antonyms
     4            English      Synonyms
```

The second table is

**Table Name : UserStatus**

```
Id     userId    status         onlineTestId
1       1        Finished           1
2       1        Not Finished       2
3       2        Not Finished       1
4       2        Finished           3
5       3        Not Finished       4
```

***Result***

```
OnlineTestId    userId        status
    1               1         Finished
    2               1         Not Finished
    3               null      null
    4               null      null
```

I have tried this query,

```
select c.onlinetestid, d.userid, d.status from onlinetest c left join userstatus d on d.onlinetestid = c.onlinetestid
where c.category = 'English' and d.userid = 1;
```

But this query is bring the first two row of the result and not the last two, in which the userId and status are null.

How to bring the above result?

Comment: move the where condition to on clause `on d.onlinetestid = c.onlinetestid and c.category = 'English' and d.userid = 1`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Place the `d.userid = 1` predicate in the `ON` clause:

```
select c.onlinetestid, d.userid, d.status 
from onlinetest c 
left join userstatus d on d.onlinetestid = c.onlinetestid and d.userid = 1
where c.category = 'English'
```

This will return all rows from `onlinetest`, having columns of `userstatus` filled with `null`s where predicate `d.userid = 1` fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use left outer Join as below :

```
SELECT        c.OnlineTestId, d.userId, d.status
FROM            OnlineTest AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         UserStatus AS d ON d.onlineTestId = c.OnlineTestId AND d.userId = 1
WHERE        (c.category = 'English')
```